# Why are these array elements null?

Tags: java, arrays, null

I have an array which has been initialised with another.

```
a1 = a2; //right hand side is actually a method returning an array
```

I can append the returned array elements to a JTextArea but printing them out produces null in the console.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a1.lenght; i++) {
    outputTextArea.append(a1[i]);
    System.out.println(a1[i]);
}
```

Why is this? Thank you.

This is the method:

```
public String[] searchString(ArrayList<String> content, String string){
    stringArray = new String[content.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < content.size(); i++){
        if(string.equals(content.get(i))){
            if(content.indexOf(string) == 0) {
                stringArray[i] = content.get(i) + " " + content.get(i+1) + "\n";
            } else if ((content.indexOf(string) > 0) && (content.indexOf(string) < (content.size()-1))) {
                stringArray[i] = content.get(i-1) + " " + content.get(i) + " " + content.get(i + 1) + "\n";
            } else if ((content.indexOf(string)) == (content.size()-1)) {
                stringArray[i] = content.get(i -1) + " " + content.get(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return stringArray;
}
```

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://sccee.org).

Comment: show us the method which returns the array and assigns it to `a1`

Comment: Need to see all your code, but a couple of problems. The code sample wouldn't actually work as you've put `a1.lenght` when it would need to be `a1.length`. Are you also sure that the RHS is actually returning anything from the method? Do you have the code sample of that method?

Comment: Hint: `new Object[SIZE]` create a new array of Objects, of size SIZE, with all elements as null.

Comment: `a1.lenght` is most certainly a typo  in his sample code (not in OP's original code).

Comment: Also: Consider using a for-each loop if you only use `a1[i]` - it is more elegant & readable.

Comment: *never ever* forget to place {} around your if-statements, even if the only contain a single line.

Comment: @amit. Thanks that was indeed the culprit. Problem solved solved by changing it to an array list.

Answer (score 0):

The Output **NULL** not from **a1** but from **a2**

you have **if** statement :

```
if (string.equals(content.get(i))) {
   .....
}
```

without **else** , so if the **string != content.get(i)** , so it will return **null** in this index at (**a2**)

so you may need to initialize a2 with values , or make check like this : **if(a1[i] != null)**

```
for(int i = 0; i < a1.lenght; i++){
       if(a1[i]!=null){///////////to avoid the null values
        outputTextArea.append(a1[i]);
        System.out.println(a1[i]);
        }
   }
```

the second problem you will face in this code (When you repeated your **string** in **content** array):

```
stringArray[i] = content.get(i) + " " + content.get(i + 1) + "\n";
```

if i = content.size() ,so ( i+1 ) will **IndexOutOfBoundsException**

Comment: Even when the string is equal to content.get(i) I get null. Also there is no out of bounds exception here as as its being checked to make sure the line you refer to  only executes if the string is at index 0 of the array list, the array list is never < 2 in length.

Comment: in case of your string repeated in content array , for ex: you have in content array ("L", "b" , "L") and the string is "L" , when you in index "2" and you do this: if(content.indexOf(string)==0),it  will return True ,  but actually you in index =2 , in this case it will return out of bounds , that's what i mean

Comment: and i try your code , it gave me null but when i enter string in content array , i get at least one value and the rest of content array (a1) and (a2) is null

Comment: in index 2 ,your check is :  if(content.indexOf(string)==0) which return true , because according to my above example (content array ("L", "b" , "L") )  ,you check on the index in where the string = "L" and the answer will be index 0 , so please try this example  and you will see what i mean

Comment: I have tried it and I appreciate your help. But you are not correct in this instance. When the loop iterates and reaches i = 2 indexOf(string) is 2, so 2 == 0 returns false.

Comment: when it's index is 0 it's doing what it's supposed to, which is getting element 0 and 1